# How to make Picker onChange update a selected struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

I have two structures. One of these structures `Idea` has a field that stores an instance of the other structure `Option`. In turn, `Option` has a list of IDs of `Idea` structures associated with it.

I created a Picker that onChange of `Idea.Option` adds the id of this idea to the list of associated ideas in Option.

This throws this error.
[image: This throws this error.]

Here's the code

```
//ContentView
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var options: [Option] = [
        Option(name: "option1", assositatedIdea: []),
        Option(name: "option2", assositatedIdea: []),
        Option(name: "option3", assositatedIdea: [])
    ]
    
    @Binding var ideas: Idea
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Option: \(ideas.option.name)", selection: $ideas.option) {
            ForEach(options) {option in
                Text(option.name).tag(option)
            }
        }.onChange(of: ideas.option) {newOption in
            ideas.option.addAssosiatedIdea(ideaId: ideas.id)
        }
        
    }
}

struct Option: Hashable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var assositatedIdea: [UUID] // Stores IDs of structs of Ideas
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, assositatedIdea: [UUID]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.assositatedIdea = assositatedIdea
        
    }
    
    mutating func addAssosiatedIdea(ideaId: UUID) {
        
        
        if (assositatedIdea.contains(ideaId)) {
            return
        }
        self.assositatedIdea.append(ideaId)
    }

}

extension Option {
    static var emptyOption: Option {
        Option(name: "", assositatedIdea: [])
    }
}

struct Idea {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var option: Option
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, option: Option) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.option = option
        
    }

}
```

```
// test1App.swift 
import SwiftUI

@main
struct test1App: App {
    
    @State var ideas: Idea = Idea(name: "big brain idea", option: Option.emptyOption)
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(ideas: $ideas)
        }
    }
}
```

I want Picker to preview the new Option. However, Picker refresehs and displays the first Option in `options`.

I did some print debugging and found out that in fact, Idea gets its field updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Firstly, here is an explanation for the error.

- Your struct `Option` has an id of type `UUID`.
- Every `Option` therefore has a unique but unpredictable id.
- You are creating the `Picker` using an array of `Option`, which is local to the view `ContentView`.
- You are binding the `Picker` to `$ideas.option`.
- The bound value is not going to match any of the `Option` in the array, because it is sure to have its own unique id.
- This is why the `Picker` gives the error that *"the selection [Option] is invalid and does not have an associated tag"*.

Another reason why two `Option` will probably not match is because each `Option` has an array of `UUID`. These are the ids of the associated `Idea`.

**Quick fix**

1. The quick way to fix the issues is to make sure that two options that are supposed to be the same actually compare as equal. So instead of using an id of type `UUID`, you could use a simple `Int`. In order to ignore the associated ids, you should also implement your own equality function:

```swift
struct Option: Hashable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int // <- not UUID
    var name: String
    var assositatedIdea: [UUID] // Stores IDs of structs of Ideas

    init(id: Int, name: String, assositatedIdea: [UUID]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.assositatedIdea = assositatedIdea
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
```

2. The empty option can have an id of 0:

```swift
    static var emptyOption: Option {
        Option(id: 0, name: "", assositatedIdea: [])
    }
```

3. Even with these changes in place, the picker will still complain that the option held by the binding does not match any tag, because you are creating `ideas` with an empty option. So include an empty option in the list of pickable options:

```swift
    var options: [Option] = [
        Option(id: 0, name: "empty", assositatedIdea: []), // <- ADDED
        Option(id: 1, name: "option1", assositatedIdea: []),
        Option(id: 2, name: "option2", assositatedIdea: []),
        Option(id: 3, name: "option3", assositatedIdea: [])
    ]
```

**Alternative model**

The changes above get it working, but it's still a bit messy. In particular, the way that `Option` holds a collection of `Idea` ids means the two structs are inter-dependent.

Here are some suggestions on how the data model and implementation could perhaps be made a bit cleaner:

- Use an enum to define the possible options, if possible (this works if the options are fixed and known in advance).
- Use `let` instead of `var` whenever possible.
- Instead of having the Options know about the Ideas that reference them, use another new type to model this relationship.
- Instead of collecting the ids (UUID) of the Ideas, just collect the actual Ideas.
- `Idea` probably doesn't need an id at all.

The following illustrates how it can be implemented this way. The new type that models the relationship between `Option` and associated `Ideas` is `OptionAndIdeas`, which is a class type. The class `AllOptionsAndIdeas` is a wrapper for a map of these classes.

```swift
enum Option: Int, Identifiable {
    case empty = 0
    case option1 = 1
    case option2 = 2
    case option3 = 3

    var id: Int {
        self.rawValue
    }

    var asString: String {
        "\(self)"
    }
}

struct Idea: Equatable {
    let option: Option
    let name: String
}

class OptionAndIdeas {
    let option: Option
    var associatedIdeas: [Idea]

    init(option: Option, associatedIdeas: [Idea] = []) {
        self.option = option
        self.associatedIdeas = associatedIdeas
    }

    func addAssociatedIdea(idea: Idea) {
        if !associatedIdeas.contains(idea) {
            associatedIdeas.append(idea)
        }
    }

    func removeAssociatedIdea(idea: Idea) {
        if let index = associatedIdeas.firstIndex(of: idea) {
            associatedIdeas.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

class AllOptionAndIdeas {

    /// A map of OptionAndIdeas, keyed by option
    private var allOptionsAndIdeas = [Option: OptionAndIdeas]()

    func switchIdeaToOption(idea: Idea, option: Option) -> Idea {

        // Remove the idea from its previous association
        if let optionAndIdeas = allOptionsAndIdeas[idea.option] {
            optionAndIdeas.removeAssociatedIdea(idea: idea)
        }
        // Re-create the idea, associating it with the new option
        let result = Idea(option: option, name: idea.name)

        // Update the associations between options and ideas
        let optionAndIdeas = allOptionsAndIdeas[option] ?? OptionAndIdeas(option: option)
        optionAndIdeas.addAssociatedIdea(idea: result)
        allOptionsAndIdeas[option] = optionAndIdeas

        return result
    }
}

struct PickerExample: View {

    private let options: [Option] = [ .empty, .option1, .option2, .option3 ]

    @Binding private var idea: Idea
    private let allOptionsAndIdeas: AllOptionAndIdeas
    @State private var selectedOption: Option

    init(idea: Binding<Idea>, allOptionsAndIdeas: AllOptionAndIdeas) {
        self._idea = idea
        self.allOptionsAndIdeas = allOptionsAndIdeas
        self._selectedOption = State(initialValue: idea.wrappedValue.option)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Option", selection: $selectedOption) {
            ForEach(options) { option in
                Text(option.asString).tag(option)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedOption) { newOption in

            // Switch to the selected option
            idea = allOptionsAndIdeas.switchIdeaToOption(idea: idea, option: newOption)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private let allOptionsAndIdeas = AllOptionAndIdeas()
    @State private var bigBrainIdea = Idea(option: .empty, name: "big brain idea")

    var body: some View {
        PickerExample(idea: $bigBrainIdea, allOptionsAndIdeas: allOptionsAndIdeas)
    }
}
```

Comment: Since in my project both `Idea` and `Option` are user-made, I decided that having a data structure binding these two is optional. The bindings will occur on App init. Thanks for the tips!